# Swift 4.2 already in Documentation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am currently using Xcode Version 9.4.1 and Swift 4.1.
My Question: Is in the official documentation already showing Swift 4.2 Stuff since it now happened several times that I found certain objects or methods which were not recognised by Xcode.
If that is the case, does it show that somewhere in the Documentation.

Also is there any way to get Swift 4.2 without installing the Buggy Beta Version of Xcode 10?

Thanks a lot for all the Help!

Comment: I thought xcode 10 only supports swift 4.2. I hate xcode 10 as well, I got back to xcode 9.4 and started dealing with swift 4.1 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically Swift 4.2 hasn't been released yet so it's a "Buggy Beta Version" as well.

If you're using the documentation on https://developer.apple.com, it will show the latest changes for the beta version of Xcode.

The documentation from within Xcode will only contain APIs included with that version of Xcode.

You could install a [Swift 4.2 snapshot](https://swift.org/blog/4-2-release-process/) to use in Xcode 9.4 but I'd just wait for Xcode 10 and swift 4.2 to be released.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at this git repo which contains a list of syntax changes. Please feel free to contribute with the changes you've met in your project.

https://github.com/alexliubj/Swift-Migration-4.2